# AngularJs $location.path with full url

Tags: angularjs

I want to route the user to an url if he clicks ok in a modal. In my controller i receive urls like

```
var newUrl = http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard

var newUrl = http://localhost:3000/#/users
```

as variable.

If i then use

```
$location.path(newUrl);
```

it does not work. I also tried

```
$location.url(newUrl);
```

but my URL gets encoded like this.

```
http://localhost:3000/#/#%2Fdashboard
```

Is there a way to get only the path of the url?

Edit

this code is part of a service. A user make some inputs in a form and clicks on another link for example in the menu. Then a popup appears where he is asked to skip his form changes. If he clicks yes i get the requested url. This is from my development environment on the server of course it will be another url. So i can not just use

```
$location.path("/users")
```

for example

Comment: Simply do:  `$location.path('/users')` or `newUrl = '/users'`

Comment: yes this works but i receive a full url as a parameter.

Comment: I reported this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8617

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073815/redirect-to-an-absolute-url-in-angularjs
 suggests that you use $window.location.href = newUrl

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this same problem when having Angular preventDefault $locationChangeStart events, force a save, and only redirect upon success. I define the following function in the body of the controller:

```
var baseLen = $location.absUrl().length - $location.url().length;
function getPath(fullUrl) { 
    return fullUrl.substring(baseLen);
}
```

It doesn't seem like a clean solution, but as a work around, it does the job. A RegEx might work better for you, if you don't know that your URLs are pointing to the same site.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `$location.absUrl()`.

See the official documentation: [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

> This method is getter only.
>
> Return full url representation with all segments encoded according to rules specified in RFC 3986.

Comment: As you say, absUrl is a getter and not a setter, so how does this answer the question?!

Answer (score 6):

May I offer a different solution:

```
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e) {
      if (meetsTheRequirementsToLeave()) {
        return;
      }
      var newPath = $location.path();
      e.preventDefault();
      checkIfUserWantsToLeave().then(function() {
        $location.path(newPath);
      });
    });
```

Within this event `$location.path()` returns the new path.

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution +1