# redirect to an absolute url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to redirect user to an absolute url in angularjs.

For example:
i have a page, my current url (http://example.com/submit), 
once the user click some button in the web page, he has to get redirected to some other web page for example ('http://google.com').

I tried using

```
$location.absUrl() == 'http://www.google.com'
$location.path('http://www.google.com')
$location.url('http://www.google.com')
```

But nothing works.

**Note:** 
The rediretion should not occur from the web-server. Its an REST API.
Wanted to achieve in client side(using angularjs) if the user is valid user(authenticated user), redirected him to portal)

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use the browser level API, with the object `window`, or you can inject the `$window` reference in your controller.

- `window.location.href="http://www.google.com";`
- `$window.location.href="http://www.google.com";`

References:

[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

[$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window)

Best solution should be perform redirect in your `$routeProvider` configuration, injecting the `$window` object and performing all redirection you need.

Answer (score 2):

What about simple `window.location.href = "http://google.com"`?

Comment: is there a way in angularjs, may be any api ?

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues with the above solutions and came across this and thought I would share.  Be sure to inject '$timeout', '$window' into your controller.

```
        $timeout(function() {
             $window.location.assign('https://URL');

         }, 3000);
```

Comment: Only after using the $timeout did this work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.location.href=""`
and in between your quotes you can place your respective url