# Trying to link to specific page within angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, routes

I'm using an api that requires me to pass in a url as part of a callback so that after it authenticates a user, it knows where to send them as part of the flow.

I know that if this were happening on the front-end I would somehow use the $location feature angular provides, but the callback url must be specified on my node.js server in the code below. I have it linking to my github url just to make sure it is actually getting executed, but I need it to link to my `content.html` page on my `localhost:8887`. I know it'd be `localhost:8887/content.html` if I weren't using AngularJS , but I don't know to do it using Angular.

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res){
    var emailAdd = req.body.text;

    ctxioClient.accounts(ID).connect_tokens().post({callback_url: "https://github.com/ralphie9224", email: emailAdd},
        function(err, response){
        res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.send(response.body);
        console.log("this was the post response: " + response.body);
    });
});
```

Comment: just to clarify, your router(nodejs) is sending you a response, and you are not sure how to forward it to the right url(`callback_url`) using angularjs?

Comment: @mido22 not quite, it happens in my node.js router and I need it to redirect my user back to a page inside my Web app who's routing is getting taken care of with angularjs.

Comment: does this post help ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073815/redirect-to-an-absolute-url-in-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073815/redirect-to-an-absolute-url-in-angularjs)